# FontRegistry and Dispose in SWT (JFace)

Tags: java, swt, jface

I'm learning how to use the FontRegistry and how it works.
At the moment I have a centralized class (FontUtils) that at startup load all the font data like this:

```
fontRegistry.put("small",new FontData[]{new FontData("Tahoma",8, SWT.BOLD)});
```

Later on in my program I use this:

```
gc.setFont(FontUtils.getFont("small"));
```

I was wondering if I have to dispose the font created in the FontUtils, because basing on the documentation every time you create a font you should dispose it.
But FontRegistry doesn't know anything about the creation of the font, indeed it doesn't have a method called dispose.
Do I have to take care of the dispose by myself?

Fore instance using a variable that counts how many resources are using the font and if it's 0 dispose the font?

Because I'm going to do the same for ImageRegistry I thing the behavior is the same , right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FontRegistry` manages all the Fonts that it owns and deals with disposing of them.

The JavaDoc says:

> A font registry owns all of the font objects registered with it, and
>   automatically disposes of them when the SWT Display that creates the
>   fonts is disposed. Because of this, clients do not need to (indeed,
>   must not attempt to) dispose of font objects themselves.

This is done using the `disposeExec` method of `Display`.

`ImageRegistry` is the same:

> An image registry owns all of the image objects registered with it,
>   and automatically disposes of them when the SWT Display that creates
>   the images is disposed. Because of this, clients do not need to
>   (indeed, must not attempt to) dispose of these images themselves.

`ImageRegistry` does also have a `dispose` method if you want to dispose of images earlier.

Note: It is possible to create an `ImageRegistry` using your own `ResourceManager`, in this case it is up to the resource manager to arrange disposal.